# How authenticate a Spring non-web Websocket over STOMP Java client using SockJs?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, sockjs

How authenticate a Spring non-web Websocket over STOMP Java client using SockJs?

Session-based Authentication? Token-based Authentication?

The documentation say:

Existing Web applications already use HTTP based authentication. For example

> Spring Security can secure the HTTP URLs of the application as usual.
>   Since a WebSocket session begins with an HTTP handshake, that means
>   URLs mapped to STOMP/WebSocket are already automatically protected and
>   require authentication. Moreover the page that opens the WebSocket
>   connection is itself likely protected and so by the time of the actual
>   handshake, the user should have been authenticated.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-stomp-authentication

Actually I connect without autentication and I'm sending messages. My Java server application use Spring framework, but my clients are java clients, not web clients.

Answer (score 3):

Official doc says:

```
String url = "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/endpoint";
StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
stompClient.connect(url, sessionHandler);
```

but there is other connect method with additional parameter WebSocketHttpHeaders. I used it for basic authorization:

```
WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
String auth = "user" + ":" + "password";
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes())));
stompClient.connect(url, headers, new MyStompSessionHandler());
```